# How to take a screenshot of specific part of webpage just like Firefox screenshot not using HTML canvas?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to have a cursor to drag and take screenshot of dragged area on HTML webpage. I tried using HTML canvas but it takes screenshot of specific `div` not the selected region on HTML webpage.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas

You will want to then have to extract the portion of the canvas you need from the mousedown/mouseup events.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The new [html2canvas version 1](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases/) has `width`, `height`, `x` and `y` options.

You can make use of these options to achieve a cropping feature the Firefox's Screenshot's way.

```js
document.onmousedown = startDrag;
document.onmouseup = endDrag;
document.onmousemove = expandDrag;

var dragging = false,
  dragStart = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  },
  dragEnd = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  };

function updateDragger() {
  dragger.classList.add('visible');
  var s = dragger.style;
  s.top = Math.min(dragStart.y, dragEnd.y) + 'px';
  s.left = Math.min(dragStart.x, dragEnd.x) + 'px';
  s.height = Math.abs(dragStart.y - dragEnd.y) + 'px';
  s.width = Math.abs(dragStart.x - dragEnd.x) + 'px';
}

function startDrag(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  dragging = true;
  dragStart.x = dragEnd.x = evt.clientX;
  dragStart.y = dragEnd.y = evt.clientY;
  updateDragger();
}

function expandDrag(evt) {
  if (!dragging) return;
  dragEnd.x = evt.clientX;
  dragEnd.y = evt.clientY;
  updateDragger();
}

function endDrag(evt) {
  dragging = false;
  dragger.classList.remove('visible');
  // here is the important part
  html2canvas(document.body, {
      width: Math.abs(dragStart.x - dragEnd.x),
      height: Math.abs(dragStart.y - dragEnd.y),
      x: Math.min(dragStart.x, dragEnd.x),
      y: Math.min(dragStart.y, dragEnd.y)
    })
    .then(function(c) {
      document.body.appendChild(c);
    });
  dragStart.x = dragStart.y = dragEnd.x = dragEnd.y = 0;
}
```

```css
* {
  user-select: none;
}

#dragger {
  position: fixed;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  border: 1px dashed white;
  pointer-events: none;
  display: none;
}

#dragger.visible {
  display: block;
}

canvas {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases/download/v1.0.0-alpha.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <p> Drag to take a screenshot ...</p>
  <img crossOrigin src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/4e90e48s5vtmfbd/aaa.png" width="120" height="120">
</div>

<div id="dragger" tabindex></div>
```

Comment: The co-ordinates are not working properly while used in IE 11 on server. Is there any work around for it @Kaiido ?